# Opening a boost socket with zero padding IP string

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, tcp

I'm using boost 1.53 and have the following code for opening a socket :

```
void openConnection(std::string ip, std::string port)
{
   tcp::resolver resolver_( m_ioService );
   tcp::resolver::query query(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), ip, port);
   tcp::resolver::iterator iterator = resolver_.resolve(query);

   boost::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> socket_(new tcp::socket(m_ioService));

   boost::asio::connect(*socket_, iterator);
   m_tcpSocket = socket_;
}
```

If I use ip = "192.168.2.50" I'm fine but if I use "192.168.002.050" I'm failed opening a connection.

Is there any way to tune tcp::resolver::query object for such kind of strings ?

Comment: Which constructor overload  `query` do you target there? http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__basic_resolver_query/basic_resolver_query.html

Answer (score 0):

If `192.168.002.50` does work I'd say it's a failed attempt at octal decoding (that shouldn't happen).

Otherwise it seems like a limitation  in `boost::asio::ip::address_v::from_string`. This will - no doubt - have reasonable grounds (I don't have the RFCs memorized).

You can always just manually parse, and use the constructor that takes the octets:

```
  address_v4(address_v4::bytes_type {192,168,2,50});
```

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__address_v4.html